# How to select attribute over another through model builder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arctoolbox

I have a gas main feature that I was asked to add MEASUREDLENGTH field to. I currently have a model that uses Shape_Length to sum overall pipe, but was asked to alter the model to use the new MEASUREDLENGTH field if populated, else use the Shape_Length field to sum overall pipe.

Can this be done with the Calculate Tool?

Comment: can you change the schema of the table? If so I would add a column for lengthToUse or something, then calculate = MEASUREDLENGTH where MEASUREDLENGTH is not null, then = Shape_Length where lengthToUse is (still) null

Comment: That'd work, but the model would have to do that for every project that it'd need to run on. I was looking for a check rather than creating another new column to fill in NULL values from the MEASUREDLENGTH column.

Comment: Add Field and Calculate Field are tools that can be added to your model, is your concern the time it would take to add and populate a single field to work from? It could be done in a Python script as well, with a da.SearchCursor and some clever summing, but that solution would depend on how you use/report the sum of each main.

I don't know of any if/else logic in modelbuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select by attributes on `MEASUREDLENGTH is not Null` or maybe `MEASUREDLENGHT>0` depending on your data
2. Summarize MEASUREDLENGTH, for example with [Summary Statistics](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm)
3. Switch selection with [Select Layer By Location](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-location.htm) using selection_type `SWITCH_SELECTION`
4. Summarize Shape_Length
5. Sum the two sums

Or you could do it with python:

```
import arcpy
input_fc=r'C:\Test.gdb\pipes'
fieldlist=['MEASUREDLENGHT','SHAPE@LENGTH']
sumlist=[]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table=input_fc,field_names=fieldlist) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if (row[0] is None or row[0]==0):
            sumlist.append(row[1])
        else:
            sumlist.append(row[0])
print sum(sumlist)
```

Comment: This would certainly work if the sum of all main is the only sum needed, I was thinking there may need to be subtotals by material, pressure, system... but then I suppose those could just be done via different table views.

Comment: Yes but for now he is only asking for total sum.

Comment: I was only providing more context surrounding the different suggestions ;)